# Install error for scikit Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikits, scikit-image

From the windows command prompt when I try to run the set up I get this error:

```
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\cl.e
xe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\P
ython27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27
\PC /Tcskimage\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\skimage
\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.obj
unwrap_2d_ljmu.c
skimage\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.c(181) : error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identi
fier
skimage\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.c(182) : error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identi
fier
skimage\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.c(194) : error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identi
fier
skimage\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.c(195) : error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identi
fier
skimage\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.c(621) : error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identi
fier
skimage\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.c(690) : error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identi
fier
error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\cl.ex
e /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\cor
e\include -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\inclu
de -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcskimage\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7
\Release\skimage\exposure\unwrap_2d_ljmu.obj" failed with exit status 2
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get the scikit installed? Thanks!

Comment: Are you missing a prerequisite python module? Like numPy for example, that is required for install?

Comment: No, previously I was missing Cython module, which it alerted me to and I installed it.  When I opened the file that raises the error (unwrap_2d_ljmu.cs) in VS 2012 the corresponding lines refer to a variable M_PI that it seems to have a problem w/. I'm going to try pip tonight, and also see if I can alter that C# file code safely.  My last resort will be to uninstall VS 2012. Something is leading me to believe the declaration in that file is outdated and my VS 2012 doesn't like it.

Comment: Could you try to add the following to unwrap_2d_ljmu.c, just before the ``#include <math.h>`` line?

``#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES``

If that works, then we can update the source accordingly.

Comment: Would you mind filing a pull-request so that this also fixes the problem for others?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I installed it by pip (also on windows) and it installed fine

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

check [about pip, and installing pip on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

**update**
Do you have all dependencies ? In log above i see NumPy but no SciPy. Maybe that's the problem.

**solution**
SciKit-Learn "unwrap_2d_ljmu.c" file is messed up.
Add `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` identifier in it. 
check [undeclared identifier and math constants](http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/_use_math_defines-m_pi-undeclared-identifier-and-math-constants-in-cc/)

Comment: I have all dependencies, the problem is the file as described in my above comment, I will try pip though tonight, thanks.

Comment: hmm, maybe their .c file is messed up and they dont add <code>_USE_MATH_DEFINES</code> in it. Look at it : http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/_use_math_defines-m_pi-undeclared-identifier-and-math-constants-in-cc/

Comment: Thanks this was it, great article!

Comment: I added this to my answer for other users searching for solution. PS did you report this bug to SciKit-Learn ?